# Custom URL Extensions/Routing Without IIS Access

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have a need to use extensionless URLs.  I do not have access to IIS (6.0) so I cannot map requests to ASP.NET and handle with a HttpHandler/HttpModule.  However, I can set a custom 404 page via web host control panel.

My current plan is to perform necessary logic in the custom 404 page, but it "feels wrong".  Are there any recommendations that I am missing?

Edited: Added "Without IIS Access" to the title since someone thought this was a repeat question.

Comment: Sorry, Q open again. I should go to sleep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to IIS, that would be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

The 404 page really is your only option if you can't map the requests. I've seen several blog packages that do this to enable magic URLs like .../archive/YYYY/MM/DD and such - there's no such page, so it hits the 404 page and the 404 page does the redirection.